# flask babel doesn't work with string returned by view

Tags: flask, flask-babel

Sorry, I'm new on flask-babel, and also on flask!
My flask code:

**test.py**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['BABEL_DEFAULT_LOCALE'] = 'en'
babel = Babel(app)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    message = _(u'测试  页面')
    return render_template('index.html', message=message)
```

**index.html**

```
<h1>{{ _("测试") }}</h1>
<h2>{{ _("消息：%(m)s", m=message) }}</h2>
```

**message.po**

```
#: learnflask.py:23
msgid "测试  页面"
msgstr "test page"

#: templates/index.html:8
msgid "测试"
msgstr "Test"

#: templates/index.html:9
#, python-format
msgid "消息：%(m)s"
msgstr "message: %(m)s"
```

---

The result:

> Test
>
> 消息：测试 页面

The first string is translate correctly, but not the second one. I want to know how to make it work. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OK. I find the answer. It's almost like you should delete the .mo file whenever you update the .po file. 
I delete `message.mo`, and use `python compile -d translations` to genrate a new `message.mo`, then it works fine!